# Jquery Autocomplete failing to call jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("getLeagues")',
            minLength: 2

        })
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Select League to Join</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LeagueId, "League", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("League", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
```

Problem is, it's not calling the function at all. I have imported everything correctly and yet I get "This breakpoint will not be hit", I've tried changing various things but still cannot get it to call to the function.

**Fixed - heres how**
Removed render in auto complete file and just had the link to the jquery UI. In the _Layout.cshtml I moved the @scripts.render from the body to the header.. And that was it... Shame it only took 3 hours to fix :(

Comment: `source: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("getLeagues"), true))`

Comment: Didn't work, the problem is that it's not even reaching the function to do anything :(

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any JS error.

Comment: I am getting this - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
And event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Just narrowed it down too  - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Comment: @GavinSweeney - sounds like jQuery UI is not being loaded properly.  Ensure that it is loading after jQuery and before you are calling the autocomplete.  On the newer MVC templates, scripts are located at the bottom of the page, which causes issues when you have inline javascript like above.

Comment: YAAAAAAAYYY I GOD DAMN FIXED IT. Heres how: On the Layout_cshtml I moved the @render files up to the header where the others were. And that was pretty much it (I also needed the link to the Jquery UI in my autocomplete file though and that was it.)